# MySQL If Date statement?

Tags: mysql, date, if-statement

Is there a way to return true or false via mysql query?

I have a table:

```
id | start 
4  | 2012-03-01 00:00:00
8  | 2012-01-20 00:00:00
```

I'd like to return either `TRUE` if the current date is greater than the start date and `FALSE` if it isn't.  I know I can do comparisons via PHP, but am wondering if I can do it via query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select case when now() > start_date 
            then true 
            else false
       end
from your_table
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT IF(CURDATE() > `start`, TRUE, FALSE) as QueryResult
FROM `tableName`
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do it in MySQL query. And you can do it in WHERE like this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE IF (CURDATE() > start_date, 1, 0) = 1;
```

this query will select only rows that are 'higher' then column 'start_date' (start_date must be type DATE)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CURDATE() > Start_Date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [BitOutput],
       CASE WHEN CURDATE() > Start_Date THEN true ELSE false END [BooleanOutput],
       CASE WHEN CURDATE() > Start_Date THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END [TextOutput]
```

Comment: Correct - changed GETDATE to CURDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I know this, but it returns the date itself and not boolean.

```
SELECT GREATEST( '2011-12-31 23:59:59', `2012-12-31 23:59:59` ) AS great_date
FROM your_table
```