# MySQLUpdate - Set Field if date has not passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question regarding case/if statements in MySQL in regards to updating a field based on the possibility of a date in a field. I have two fields. One that contains a date ("LastDayToNotify") and one that contains a plaintext message ("NotifyMessage")

The date field can contain one of three values - An empty field, a Null, or a Date.

My question is - Is it possible, and if so how, to in MySQL to have a query that sets one field's value (NotifyMessage) based on if the date (LastDayToNotify) has passed? An example would be :

If the date has not passed (the date is today or before), update the NotifyMessage field to say "Generic Message"

but if the date field is empty, null, or it is passed it does nothing.

I've tested a couple modifactions of answers in this thread, but have been unable to successfully account for all 3 possible date scenarios. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178982/mysql-if-date-statement)

I know this is probably a rookie question, but I've never encountered this particular need yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using sane field types (`date` or `datetime`)...

```
UPDATE table
SET
    NotifyMessage = 'Generic Message'
WHERE
    LastDayToNotify IS NOT NULL
    AND LastDayToNotify >= CURDATE();
```

If you're not already storing the dates as `date` types, take a look at: [Converting a date in MySQL from string field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861489/converting-a-date-in-mysql-from-string-field)

Comment: Not sure which way you want the `<` vs `>=` - your logic is a bit unclear ("If the date has not passed (the date is today or before")

Comment: I am storing the data in a Date Field, So I think I am good there. As far as the logic - I may have misspoke. The LastDayToNotify is the last day that we will set the message. So that means that if the date has passed - We will no longer be offering the message, but if the date is today, or in the future we will set the date until the date has passed.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you cant set a value with a CASE statement but you can list something. This however will appear as a separate column.

E.G

```
    CASE WHEN date < SELECT DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    THEN "Generic Message"
    ELSE 0 
    END AS 'Before Today'
```

You would have to then create more case statements to cover other scenarios such as NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple query:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET NotifyMessage = 'Generic Message'
WHERE LastDayToNotify <= CURDATE();
```

Comment: Whilst this isn't a bad answer, it could be improved if you explain why this solves it and what was wrong in the first place.